# How can I synthesise a Task Stack using Intents with appropriated data?

Tags: android, android-activity

Lets say I have 3 Activities defined as follows:

```
ACTIVITY                  PARENT

ClassActivity             -
StudentActivity           ClassActivity
StudentExamActivity       StudentActivity
```

In the application's normal workflow, the user should be able to select a student in `ClassActivity`. This will start `StudentActivity` passing the student's content uri, represented here as `<STUDENT_ID_URI>` (to be handled by a ContentResolver), in the intent to specify what should be displayed. Similarly, an exam can be selected in `StudentActivity` by starting `StudentExamActivity` and passing its uri, represented as `<EXAM_ID_URI>`.

The question is: what if I need to start `StudentExamActivity` directly (e.g. from a notification or an external application)? How can I assure that when `StudentExamActivity` is started with the `<EXAM_ID_URI>` data, its parent (`StudentActivity`) will be started with `<STUDENT_ID_URI>` when the user navigates back to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) and use it something like this

```
TaskStackBuilder stack = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
Intent classAct = new Intent(context, ClassActivity.class);
// This will clear any opened activities. Use if necessary
classAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Intent studentAct = new Intent(context, StudentActivity.class);
studentAct.putExtra("exam_id", 123);

stack.addNextIntent(home);
stack.addNextIntent(studentAct);
stack.addNextIntent(new Intent(context, StudentExamActivity.class));
stack.startActivities();
```